# Connecting three sliders with each other

Tags: java, user-controls, slider

This is more of a theoretical question than an actual coding question (I should be able to handle that part of the problem).

I have three sliders (*S1, S2, S3*). Each one of the sliders have a *min value of 0* and a *max value of 35* (each of the values in between are *int*). 
The Total sum of these three sliders can never exceed 50. It can of course be <= 50 and >= 0, but never < 0.

For example, if the initial values of S1 = 20, S2 = 11, S3 = 3. How can I connect these sliders so that if I change, e.g., S3 from value 3 to value 23, then the other sliders should change their values so that it is always between the interval 0 and 50. Or if I change S1 from 20 to value 50, then both S2 and S3 should move to 0.

Right now I have this pseudo code looking like this (This would be in the case of us changing slider S1, but I feel a lot is missing).

```
double newValue1 = 0; 
double newValue2 = 0;
if( (S1 + S2 + S3) > maxAntalRum ) {
    diff = max - (S1 + S2 + S3);  // the diff if tot value of S1-S3 exceeds 50 
    newValue1 = floor(diff/2);    // new values are divided upon the 2 sliders that we are not changing (i.e. S2 and S3). Value rounded off up.
    newValue2 = ceil(diff/2);     // Value rounded off down.
    S2 += newValue1;
    S3 += newValue2;
    sliderS2.setValue(S2);
    sliderS3.setValue(S3);
```

I'm sort of stuck. How should I proceed with this problem? Or from which angle should I process it?

Regards,

Anna

Answer (score 1):

I think you've pretty much got it.  You'll need similar code for each slider, of course.  Also, you'll need to check that you're not already adjusting a slider.  (If you only had two sliders, you might be able to skip this by checking to see if the slider value is already correct, but with three you'll change two at once and for a short time the numbers won't add up.)  So you want something like this:

```
private boolean  gate = true;   // Instance field.
```

In the methods:

```
if (gate)  {
    gate = false;
    ...
    // Your code here.
    ...
    gate = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this boolean variable completely. It does seem logical each time a slider is changed to check whether or not S1+S2+S3 lies between 0 and 50, but what should I do when it doesn't. Sometimes it seems as if the value could become negative. Is it enough with only this boolean var?

Comment: @user2481390:  No, the boolean's there to avoid an infinite loop.  Slider one moves, so you adjust slider two, which now has moved, so _its_ code runs and adjusts slider one, which adjusts slider two, which....  You'll need to add code to set the negative slider to zero and subtract the amount from the other slider.  You'll need to play with it. _First_ try to get it so the sliders stay within allowed range, then try to get them to move as rationally as possible. And try to write one method to do most of the work for all three sliders; you'll have to make fewer adjustments and have fewer bugs.

Comment: @user2481390:  Good.  That kind of think is a bit tricky, but it's pretty neat once it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class Sliders extends GridPane {

    private static final int MINIMUM = 0;
    private static final int MAXIMUM = 100;

    private ScrollBar scrollBar1;
    private ScrollBar scrollBar2;
    private ScrollBar scrollBar3;
    private boolean canUpdate = true;

    public Sliders() {
        scrollBar1 = getTrainingScrollBar(MAXIMUM, (oldValue, newValue) -> handleSliderChange(oldValue, newValue, scrollBar2, scrollBar3));
        scrollBar2 = getTrainingScrollBar(MINIMUM, (oldValue, newValue) -> handleSliderChange(oldValue, newValue, scrollBar1, scrollBar3));
        scrollBar3 = getTrainingScrollBar(MINIMUM, (oldValue, newValue) -> handleSliderChange(oldValue, newValue, scrollBar1, scrollBar2));
        this.add(scrollBar1, 0, 0);
        this.add(scrollBar2, 0, 1);
        this.add(scrollBar3, 0, 2);
    }

    private ScrollBar getTrainingScrollBar(int defaultValue, ScrollBarHandler handler) {
        ScrollBar scrollBar = new ScrollBar();
        scrollBar.setMin(MINIMUM);
        scrollBar.setMax(MAXIMUM);
        scrollBar.setPrefSize(300, 40);
        scrollBar.setValue(defaultValue);
        scrollBar.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> handler.handle(oldValue, newValue));
        return scrollBar;
    }

    private void handleSliderChange(Number oldValue, Number newValue, ScrollBar sb1, ScrollBar sb2) {
        if (canUpdate) {
            canUpdate = false;
            double value = newValue.doubleValue() - oldValue.doubleValue();
            if (isEqualToZero(value)) {
                canUpdate = true;
                return;
            }
            value = value / 2;
            if (setValueAndCheckIfSliderReachZero(sb1, sb2, value)) {
                return;
            }
            if (setValueAndCheckIfSliderReachZero(sb2, sb1, value)) {
                return;
            }

            sb1.setValue(sb1.getValue() - value);
            sb2.setValue(sb2.getValue() - value);
            canUpdate = true;
        }
    }

    private boolean setValueAndCheckIfSliderReachZero(ScrollBar scrollbar1, ScrollBar scrollbar2, double value) {
        double nextValue = scrollbar1.getValue() - value;
        if (nextValue <= 0d) {
            scrollbar1.setValue(0d);
            scrollbar2.setValue(scrollbar2.getValue() - value + nextValue);
            canUpdate = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isEqualToZero(Double number) {
        return Math.abs(number) < 0.00000001;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface ScrollBarHandler {
        void handle(Number oldValue, Number newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can please try and provide some information on what you have done (rather than just code for the answer), cheers.